# Probability of picking balls

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a box that contains 9 red balls, 7 blue balls and 2 green balls.
I randomly take out 5 balls without replacement.
I want to find the probability that I that I have exactly 2 red balls and at most 4 red balls.

Is my calculation correct?

$$P(\textrm{exactly 2 red balls})= \frac {{9\choose2}{9\choose3}} {18\choose5}$$

$$P(\textrm{at most 4 red balls})= 1-\frac {{9\choose5}{9\choose0}} {18\choose5}$$

Thank you

Comment: Yes your answers are both correct (now that the typesetting correctly matches what you intended).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That's two misreads by me on one query.  I deleted my answer (again).  That's what comes from watching the election results as I participate.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut it is correct.  Note that since we are taking five balls, we have that $P(0)+P(1)+P(2)+P(3)+P(4)+P(5)=1$.  Subtracting, we have $P(0)+P(1)+P(2)+P(3)+P(4)=1-P(5)$.  See also "Vandermonde's Identity"